# Home directory or disk encryption without filename encryption

Tags: ecryptfs, filename

Is there any way to use `ecryptfs` to encrypt the whole disk or only the home directory without simultaneously encrypting the filenames?

I'm asking this question because I have to get rid of the maximum filename length restriction of 143 characters imposed by encrypted filenames. The operating system is Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: A solution (maybe you would say wordaround) is to use another kind of encryption, encrypted disk alias LVM with encryption (LUKS encryption). It is easiest to get it during the installation (a fresh installation).

Comment: Many thanks for this hint. I also have the possibility to set a SSD password instead of running some encryption software. Do you see any shortcomings of setting a SSD password compared to encrypt the disk? Would there be a way to access my not encrypted data while the machine is either running or put to sleep? If not, a SSD password should be an alternative, no?

Comment: I don't know how an SSD password works. Let us hope that someone who knows will see your comment and reply.

Comment: You have to insert it directly after starting the machine. It's a secure way to protect your hard drive from unauthorized access if a reboot is necessary - as far as I know. That's why I'm wondering if it's possible under a Linux system to access data of an unencrypted system if the system is either locked or sleeping - without the necessity of a reboot.

Comment: Probably it works well, but you need confirmation from someone who *knows*, or from some internet site, where it is explained.

Comment: I think, I will use LVM in connection with LUKS as you've suggested in your first post. Since I'm new to Linux I'm wondering if I can use `Clonezilla`or `rsync` to backup the current installation and restore the system after I set up the encrpytion of the hard drive. Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cloning

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) will clone the current system's drive either directly to a cloned copy or to a compressed image, that can be restored to a cloned copy.

This will preserve the current partition structure, file system and encryption, and will work as a backup, but it is not very useful in order to convert the system to another kind of partition structure (LVM with LUKS encryption).

### Fresh installation often easiest and fastest

It is often easiest and fastest to make a fresh installation instead of converting from the previous system.

- Backup your personal files to another drive. You can use `rsync` or `tar` or some specialized backup program for this purpose.
- It might be a good idea to have a general backup too, and this backup can be made with Clonezilla. In that case I suggest that you make an image of the whole drive.
- Install a fresh system, in this case select [Entire disk with LVM and encryption](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/383/builds/159202/testcases/1451/results).
- Install the additional program packages that you remember (that you need).
- Copy back your personal files from the backup. It helps if you use a separate **`data`** partition for your personal data (but it is not necessary).
- Later on, when you need another program package, install it. This way you will get rid of old program packages, that you will not use.

---

Ask for details (in comments), if you have questions or need detailed explanations of some step, or if you want to modify something from this general outline.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort! I guess, I have to postpone this issue till the weekend (or even longer) and maybe further questions will pop up then. But already now I would be happy if you could answer the following questions. 1: If I choose the automatic way for fulldisk encryption during the installation, is LUKS or ecryptfs used? I'm asking because I saw poeple doing LUKS full disk encrpytion in a more complicated way while checking on the internet. 2: A backup of `/home/user` and `/etc` and in addition saving the packages list should be sufficient to restore most parts of the system, no?

Comment: @sperber, 1. Yes, I describe a method that uses LUKS; 2. It depends what you have done with the system. If all your personal files are in `/home/user`, fine, and yes, it is a good idea to backup `/etc`. I don't know what else might be affected (except of course installed programs) by your tweaks etc. It is important to preserve the permissions and ownership of the backed up files. Anyway, welcome back, when you have more questions :-)

Comment: Okay, this weekend I found some time and all worked. Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad it works for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. You can use the command `ecryptfs-migrate-home` to migrate the home directory of a user (while logged into another sudo user account). This command does not support disabling filename encryption by default, however you can modify this command's script file which is located at `/usr/bin/ecryptfs-migrate-home`.

In this script, it is using the `ecryptfs-setup-private` command to finally doing the encryption. This command supports disabling filename encryption using the `--no-fnek` flag. Look for the line where the encryption is being done and change it something like this:

```js
if ! ecryptfs-setup-private --no-fnek -u "$USER_NAME" -b $ECRYPTFS_SETUP_PRIVATE_ARGS; then
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584382/encrypting-home-folder-without-filename-encryption-using-ecryptfs/